# What is Function's Data Type : function or object? in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, types

The MDN said :

**Six data types that are primitives:**

- Boolean
- Null
- Undefined
- Number
- String
- Symbol (new in ECMAScript 6)
- **and Object**

But I confused, the function data type and object data type.

Let's see :

```
var func = function() { 
    console.log ('Hello World ! ')
};

var obj = { 
    property : something
}  


console.log(typeof(func)); // ===> function
console.log(typeof(obj)); // ===> object
```

Is it different function data type and object data type? Why `typeof(func)` is function? not a object? The document said there are 7 data type (6 primitive, 1 object). function is not include anywhere.

Until now, over 1 year, I think function's data type is object, I heard the function is first class object in JavaScript, so I don't have doubt about function is object but today I think more time, and wondered.

Is it different?

Comment: It returns function but its a function object https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: `typeof` doesn't return the *Data Type*.

Comment: `typeof` doesn't report the value's true data type. It's a lookup table that maps data type and other value characteristics to a name: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-typeof-operator . Functions are objects that have an internal `[[Call]]` property. That's why `typeof null` is `"object"` (\*grumpy face\*).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can logically think of `Function` as a subclass of `Object`.  It has all the methods of `Object` plus some more that are specific to a function (such as `.bind()`, `.call()`, `.apply()`, etc...).

Why Javascript decided to make `Function` report it's own unique type, but not `Array` (which is a similar derivation from `Object`) is anyone's guess and probably only known to the original designers of the language.  It is extremely useful that `Function` does report its own type so you can easily check if a property is callable as a function and perhaps that is the main reason why it was done this way.

Here's a demonstration of how a `Function` object has the methods from an `Object`:

```js
function f() {}
f.someProperty = "foo";

log(f.hasOwnProperty("someProperty"));
log(f instanceof Object);
log(f instanceof Function);

function log(x) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = x;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: Where would `Object.create(null)` fit in this class hierarchy?

Comment: *functions* are not characterised by being `instanceof Function` in JavaScript, they are special because they are **callable** objects.

Comment: @Bergi - But, a function is `instanceof Function`.  `Object.create(null)` is a bit of an odd beast since it has no prototype.  One could think of it as the parent of `Object`, I suppose since it offers the common property accessor syntax.

Comment: Yeah, most functions you encounter are `Function`s, but they don't have to be. They could come from another realm (frame), could have their [[prototype]] manipulated or just be host objects with a buggy implementation (oldIE's `console.log` being well known for this - these days, browser vendors care to minimise wtf moments)

Comment: @Bergi - So, now you're off description some exceptions.  `instanceof` doesn't work for all objects in another frame - that's nothing new for a function object, same issue with `instanceof Array` for example.  And, your IE comment sounds like it's a bug.  Is there something you think I should correct or improve in my answer?

Comment: I'd challenge the "*is anyone's guess*" part - `typeof x == "function"` is exactly made this way to check for callable objects.

Comment: @Bergi - That is one thing it is useful for and is probably the main reason (in other words a good guess).  I don't have any evidence about the "why" so I didn't attempt to pretend I knew the actual reasoning at the time it was designed.  I did add "perhaps that is the main reason it was done this way" to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

`typeof` returns the type of what ever is passed to it. A function is an object (`(function () {}) instanceof Object === true`), but the `typeof` function is defined to return `"function"` when an Object implements [[Call]] in ECMA-262 is supplied to it.

Functions are objects, but `typeof` treats them as a special case.

Comment: *"when an Object with a `call` method is supplied to it"* - I beg to differ. `typeof {call:function(){}}` returns `object`.

Comment: One might assume that you mean the special *internal [[call]] method*, but the wording is confusing indeed

Comment: @bergi Yeah, I changed the wording for that