# Why is the type of an instance of the GeneratorFunction constructor 'function'?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator

As I am still digging through ES6 and because I am usually very curious and I always try to find the reasons for everything, I was playing a bit with generator functions trying to understand how does a compiler like Traceur or Babel compile the ES6 code to ES5. So I saved the constructor whose instance is any generator function and I alerted the type of one of its instances. The result was 'function'

```js
window.GeneratorFunction = Object.getPrototypeOf(function*() {}).constructor
console.log(typeof new GeneratorFunction()) // 'function'
```

As far as I know, an instance of a constructor is an object

```js
console.log(typeof new String()) // 'object'
console.log(typeof new Number()) // 'object'
```

Why does the `GeneratorFunction()` constructor has function instances?

Answer (score 2):

Probably because also `typeof new Function() === 'function'` is `true`. See [What is Function's Data Type : function or object? in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35185871/3853934)

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, there are two main groups of values:

- **Primitives**, that can't hold properties, are immutable and are value-equal
- **Objects**, that can hold properties, may be mutable and are reference-equal

Primitives are strings, numbers, BigInts, symbols, booleans and nullish values (`null` and `undefined`).

Everything else are objects, including arrays, class instances, dates (not the fruit), promises and many more things.

Functions are special objects: they have all the attributes of what an object has, but one more: they are callable (I mean, `[[Call]]`able).

Constructors are only allowed to return objects, but as functions are objects too, it's valid to return functions. So do `Function`, `GeneratorFunction` and `AsyncFunction` (the latter two aren't available directly).

**But if they are objects, why doesn't `typeof` return `"object"` for them?**

That's a bit more complicated. `typeof` does weird things. For example, [it returns `"object"` for `null`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18808226/8376184), which is actually a primitive.

However, it's useful that it [returns `"function"` for **every callable object (i.e. function)**](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-typeof-operator-results), because that's the only true way to check if an object is callable (not counting `try..catch` hacks).

---

So, to sum up, `new GeneratorFunction()` returns a functions object, whose `typeof`-representation is `"function"`