# why typeof function is coming object here?

Tags: javascript

Why type of function is coming object in following javascript code?

```js
  var y = 1;
    if (function f(){}) {
     y += typeof f;
   }
  console.log(y);
```

both will give same result
Output is coming as **1object**

Shouldn't it be **1function**?

Edit1: Please see below Image I'm getting 1object in chrome 60 [image]

Comment: I get `1undefined` - so, you're wrong on both counts

Comment: `eval` "evaluates" strings ... so, you're not "evaluating" a string ... try `eval("function foo(){}");`

Comment: Or just `function foo(){}`, absolutely no reason for `eval` at all. Then it will give `1function` on chrome.

Comment: If this code made sense (it doesn't), this would be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35185871/what-is-functions-data-type-function-or-object-in-javascript

Comment: The code in the screenshot is not the same code in the question, so *of course* you get a different result.

Comment: You're being downvoted because we all get the same result in Chrome, and your screenshot contains different code.  This is not arrogance on our part, its a terrible question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Function's Data Type : function or object? in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35185871/what-is-functions-data-type-function-or-object-in-javascript)

Comment: @admin - firstly **don't accuse me of downvoting** - you have no idea at all - I tested on Firefox and Chrome - and the edited question shows a screen shot that shows this happens in Chrome 60 - yet, for me, I get `1undefined` - so, am I wrong in saying that `1undefined` is what that code produces? no, but perhaps, just perhaps there's more to what the OP did in chrome, previously defining `var f={}` - or it's defined in the page he's on as some object ... who knows ... but the code in the question, isolated, gives and will always give `1undefined`

Comment: even if you run the snippet in the question it comes up with `1undefined` (I see the code has changed, no more eval ... makes my second comment look retarded, thanks OP

Comment: I still get the same result, even with the modified code.

Comment: @admin - what do you see when you click YOUR `Run Code Snippet` button?

Comment: try this for laughs ... in the console, type `console.log(JSON.stringify(f))`

Comment: I didn't check snippet i check it on my system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting `typeof f === 'object'` from an isolated code as you've posted is not possible, since `f` is not defined in the scope you're using it. The function definition in the condition is not a function declaration, it is a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function). The name `f` is visible in the body of the newly-created function only, it is not available outside of the said function. That makes `typeof f` to return `undefined`, any other reference to `f` would fire a reference error.

Hence the only possible way to get `1object` is to define an object or array named `f` before writing the shown code in the posted screenshot, either in the console, or on the opened page behind the console.

This behavior of the named function expressions is defined in the standards. In very old IE you would get `1function`, since old IEs created a global copy of the named functions expressions too.